# HxD Hex Editor Dark Theme

Tags: darkmode, hex-editors

I believe the HxD Hex editor is one of the best hex editors on Windows. I was wondering if there is a dark mode for HxD Hex Editor. Or any settings or color codes?

Comment: This question is serious, it is ridiculous to rate down this. Thank you for your color, it saved my time!

Comment: @KhangDinhHoang I am glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

These are the colors I came up with. Inspired by Visual Studio's dark theme:

- Offsets and header: Foreground: RGB(66, 196, 173)
- Offsets and header: Background: RGB(45, 45, 48)
- Hex & text: Foreground: RGB(199, 199, 199)
- Hex & text: Background: RGB(30, 30, 30)
- Hex (odd columns): Foreground: RGB(215, 171, 105)
- Hex (odd columns): Background: None
- Modified data: Foreground: RGB(185, 117, 181)
- Modified data: Background: None
- Selection: Foreground: Highlighted Text
- Selection: Background: RGB(0, 122, 204)

[image: HxD Dark Theme]

Answer (score 2):

The above can be copy-pasted ***%AppData%\Mael Horz\HxD Hex Editor.ini*** as:

```
[\]
Theme=Default
OffsetBackColor=3157293
OffsetForeColor=11387970
DataBackColor=1973790
DataForeColor=13092807
OddHexColForeColor=6925271
SelColor=13400576
SelTextColor=-16777202
```

Comment: for me the setting was next to executable.